# How to set right column div as fixed (Currently "postition: fixed" makes section move to left side)

Tags: css, html, fixed, multiple-columns

I am trying to use div's to set up three sections, one main one in the middle and a smaller column on the left and right. I was able to do this, but cannot get right column to have a fixed position. Whenever I add "position: fixed" for this section, it ignores the "float: right" and puts the section on top of the left column. Note that I needed to order the div's left right middle in code, else the right column positions on the right side below the other content. Thanks.

```
    <div style = "height: 100%">

    <div style = "width: 15%; float:left; background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;height: 100%; background-repeat:no-
    repeat; background-position:left top; position: fixed" >
    <div style = "margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; margin-top:40px; margin-
    bottom:40px">

    <p2>
    content
    </p2>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div style = "width: 15%; float:right; background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%; min-height: 100%; background-repeat:no-
    repeat; **position: fixed;** background-position:right top">
    <div style = "margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; margin-top:40px; margin-
    bottom:40px">

    <p2>
    content
    </p2>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div style = "width: 60%; margin-left:300px; margin-right:300px; top: 100px" >
    <h1>head  </h1>
    <p>content
    </p>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you give an element fixed position, you can force its position on the screen. For example, with your div that's stuck on the left side, you can add "left: 100px" to move it 100px to the right. That is, it moves the element 100px from the left (moving it to the right). You can change this measurement to whatever works in this case, such as 75%.

Also look into CSS. Putting styling right into your markup can get messy and repetitive, and I don't know if you intended to have the page shrink with the browser window, but most webpages specify widths of columns in pixels rather than percentages.